# Returning coordinates from touches in Swift

Tags: swift, touch, coordinates

I am currently in the process of writing a PONG game in Swift. I want the player's paddle to be controlled by the player's finger, so the paddle would move where ever the player drags their finger on the screen. I want to be able to find out the coordinates of the player's finger touch so I can implement this. By searching around Google and stack overflow, I have found this function:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    }
```

Though I am not really sure what it does, how it does it and how to obtain the x and y values of the touch from it. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell my how to obtain the x/y coordinates of the users!! I want the end result to be something similar to this:

```
PlayerPaddle.center.x = XTouchCoordinate
```

THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer

Comment: Please specify how I would go about using this and what I would need to do to obtain the coordinates of the user's touch. (I am sorry as I am very new to Swift it is hard for to understand how to use this :( )

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

For dragging use UIPanGestureRecognizer as for your original question of obtaining the x and y coordinates you can use something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)
    var xcoord = location.x
    println(location.y)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**If you are using GoogleMap SDK**

```
 extension TargetViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D)    
      {

        print("Tapped at Latitude: " + String(coordinate.latitude) + ", Longitude: "
                + String(coordinate.longitude))
      }

    }
```